# re-run Python script in started in docker-compose with MySQL server running

Tags: python, mysql, docker

Using `docker compose` I've created a container for my MySQL DB and one for my Python script. When I use the command `docker compose up`, my images are built for my Python app container and my MySQL DB container, and the python script is run. After execution, the shell just hangs since MySQL server is still running and my script has completed execution. How can I either stop the MySQL server after my script runs, or re-run my script while the MySQL server continues to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running `docker-compose up`, your current shell will display all the logs from all the containers defined in the `docker-compose.yaml` file. Also if you terminate the command with `cmd + c` in MacOS, all the containers will stop running.

As a result, this gives you the impression that the shell just hangs while everything is still running as normal.

What you want in this case is to let the containers continue to run in the background ([detached mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/))

```
docker-compose up --detach
```

The MySQL server will now continue to run until you stop it with `docker-compose down`.

Comment: Thank you. IN that case, how do I re-run my script when I want to (eg every 24hours)? Do I need to do `docker-compose up` each time or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Your best bet is to 1) set the container with the script to `restart: always` so it will always be up while docker is up. 2) set the `entrypoint` and `command` to `tail -f /dev/null` so that the container will not be terminated half-way. 3) Install cronjob inside the docker container and configure it to run every 24 hours.